# How web scraping is done on Linux servers

Tags: web-scraping, server

I want to do web scraping on linux server. But linux servers don't have GUI and browser. They have only got a black screen i.e terminal. Recently I prepared a selenium script on windows using python and chromedriver which messages your friends on whatsapp. I want to deploy it on linux server. It won't run there, right? So, how is it done?

Comment: If you meant *"How do I run Selenium on Linux?"* that's a duplicate question that's been answered on SO, please use the search box to find the answer. Unless you meant *"What are web-scraping alternatives to selenium which run (natively) on Linux (without requiring any other packages)?"*

Answer (score 0):

You can run Chrome/Firefox with option `--headless`and it will run without displaying window so it will no need XWindow (GUI). It is called `headless` web browser. (And server without monitor is called `headless` server)

`Selenium` can use webdriver `PhantomJS` (instead of Chrome/Firefox) which doesn't display window (probably it uses WebKit/Qt). But this driver is not developed any more.

Linux can also use [Xfbv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) to create fake/virtual monitor and run programs which need XWindow.